# Logrotate running at wrong hour/time

Tags: ubuntu, cron, logrotate

I have the following entry in my `/etc/crontab` file to ensure that daily cronjobs run at 4:25 AM. This is the only entry for `daily` inside this file:

`25 4    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`

The contents of my `/etc/cron.daily/` includes `logrotate`:

```
 # ls -l /etc/cron.daily/
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  377 Jan 21  2019 logrotate
```

Here's the logrotate config under `/etc/logrotate.d/`

```
/var/log/remote/custom/*.log
{
        rotate 180
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
    # force rsyslog to refresh file descriptor
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
```

Why is it that when I inspect the contents of  `/var/lib/logrotate/status`, I see that the logfile is rotated at midnight and not at 4:25AM?

`"/var/log/remote/custom/cust.log" 2020-11-4-0:0:39`

Operating System: `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`
Kernel: `Linux 5.4.0-40-generic`

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "|| " in the /etc/crontab line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have overlooked /etc/anacrontab, where anacron finds when to evaluate /etc/cron.daily (and others).

Also, one of the many reasons I stay away from systemd.  Check the first lines of /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:

```
# less -X  /etc/cron.daily/logrotate                        
#!/bin/sh

# skip in favour of systemd timer
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: The system does not have `anacron` installed.

Comment: Does it have systemd installed?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's running `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` , `Linux 5.4.0-40-generic` if that helps

Comment: Then cron is not to blame, check my edited answer.

Comment: uh oh! So I could potentially fix this by commenting out the `condition` I suppose?

Comment: I would find out how to have systemd run it at the time you prefer.  If you remove that condition, the next update will come nagging.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I can use a specific time under `/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer` ... which solves it for me.

Comment: The systemd authors almost had you there, didn't they, by leaving useless /etc/cron directories around?

Comment: Exactly! that is super weird thing to do...what is the purpose of keeping logrotate (and others) in both places if one is never going to be used.

Comment: They only care about themselves - every problem is someone else's.

Answer (score 3):

For **Debian** users, you could think that's it's running at 6.25 (/etc/crontab) but since last few version, it's running at 00.00 and it's configured on **systemd** !

Old /etc/crontab :

> 25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / &&
> run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

If you wants to change execution time of systemd you have to edit this file :
**/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer**

by default it's :

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
```

If you wants to run it at 6.20 every day :

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6:20
```

(then i've rebooted system, but I'm not sure tha'ts necessary !)

Answer (score 0):

Be VERY CAREFUL when you edit `/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer` - that file is a symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.timer`.

The timer will be ignored if the file is accidentally changed from a symbolic link to a regular file, which it will be if you edit this file using (for example) sed as part of an installation script for an embedded system. Ask me how I know!